# I applied the mirror modifier to the 'c' . Is there a way to rotate both the object and its mirror together as if they are one?

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I applied the mirror modifier to the 'c'. Is there a way to rotate both the object and its mirror together as if they are one? I want to create a short animation where the objects (the "c" and its mirror) rotate together as an entity for a few seconds and then split in the middle to show the text behind. If I applied the mirror modifier, I would not be able to split them later in the animation.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an empty as mirror object and make that empty a parent of your object:

[image]

Comment: sorry but for me looks more like 2 Ks than like 2 Cs

Comment: and you are right!! Maybe you can show me how to make a C? 

Comment: isn't your name Chris? Chris with a C?????

Comment: well...official it is Christoph...but yeah...Chris is ok ;)

Comment: Oh I thought you were Jesus Chris, a bit disappointed...   :/

Comment: well...life is full of disppointments...learn to live with it!!! :D :D :D

Comment: anyway for me you'll always be the geonode messiah

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome